# Split and Loop in java 8

Tags: java, split, java-8

I have this problem which I want to solve in java 8,

I have a string which is concatenated by `.`

```
A.B.C.D
```

Number of characters in the string can vary.

I have this method, which takes the string as input and number of level deep it has to go,
I have to loop through the number that i get after applying a split on string with "." and go just given level deep

```
private String getResponse (String str, int level) {
// for now, simply print the entire string first and then start removing last alphabet of it one by one till the value of level
// ex : str = A.B.C.D
// System.out.println("Doing a call with key as = " + str); => should give me A.B.C.D
// Apply logic of split 
// System.out.println("Doing a call with key as = " + str); => should give me A.B.C
// Split again
// System.out.println("Doing a call with key as = " + str); => should give me A.B
// this should go in loop till we reach the level
}
```

Can this be done in java 8?

Comment: So what is your question? Are you trying to print out `A.B.C.D`, followed by `A.B.C`, and so on, with the last one being `A`? What do you mean by "given level deep"?

Comment: Last one may not be A, I should stop till I meet the value of level. If value of level is 2, I should stop at A.B

Comment: If level is 3, `A.B.C`? So it's like the final number of connectors, i.e. `.` in this case, should be equivalent to the `level - 1`?

Comment: If level is 3, then Just `A`. I have to start from last and move towards the first one.

Comment: You can get an array of strings with a single split.  So what's the problem?

Comment: for clarity, given input of "A.B.C.D", exactly what should be returned when level = 3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's Java-8 solution:

```
static void getResponse(String input, int level) {
    Stream.iterate(input, str -> {
        int pos = str.lastIndexOf('.');
        return pos == -1 ? "" : str.substring(0, pos);
    }).limit(level+1).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If you know for sure that level does not exceed the number of dots, you can omit the check:

```
static void getResponseUnsafe(String input, int level) {
    Stream.iterate(input, str -> str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.')))
            .limit(level + 1).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No looping is necessary, since string can be split into an array in a single `String.split` call. (Note that `String.split` takes a regex.) To handle the "level", just subtract it from the length of the array of splits. Instead of copying the array subrange, convert it into a List and use subList():

```
String getResponse(String str, int level) {
    String[] splits = str.split("\\.");
    if (level < 0 || level > splits.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return String.join(".", Arrays.asList(splits).subList(0, splits.length - level));
}
```

The output of

```
    for (int level = 0; level < 5; level++) {
        System.out.printf("level %d: %s%n", level, getResponse("A.B.C.D", level));
    }
```

will be

```
level 0: A.B.C.D
level 1: A.B.C
level 2: A.B
level 3: A
level 4:
```

Note that this does require Java 8 because it requires `String.join()`. (But it doesn't require streams or even lambdas!)

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Not solving using Java 8

```
public class StringLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        getResponse("A.B.C.D", 2);

        System.out.println();
        getResponse("A.B.C.D", 3);

    }

    // Recursive function
    private static void getResponse (String str, int level) {

        if(level < 0 || str.equals(""))
            return;

        // Prints out the current string
        System.out.println(str);

        int lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(lastIndex == - 1)
            lastIndex = 0;

        // Remove content after last connector
        // Decrement level
        getResponse(str.substring(0, lastIndex), level - 1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A.B.C.D
A.B.C
A.B

A.B.C.D
A.B.C
A.B
A
```

Answer (score 2):

Your comments mention using `split()`, so here's an example of using `split()`, `Arrays.copyOfRange()` (to remove the last letter), and `String.Join()` to put the result of `Arrays.copyOfRange()` back together for the next recursive call.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "A.B.C.D";
    getResponse(string, 3);
    System.out.println();

    getResponse(string, 2);
    System.out.println();

    getResponse(string, 1);
    System.out.println();
}

private static void getResponse(String str, int level) {
    if (level < 0 || str.isEmpty())
        return;

    System.out.println(str);

    String[] strPieces = str.split("\\.");
    if (strPieces.length > level) {
        getResponse(String.join(".", Arrays.copyOfRange(strPieces, 0, strPieces.length - 1)), level - 1);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
A.B.C.D
A.B.C
A.B
A

A.B.C.D
A.B.C
A.B

A.B.C.D
A.B.C
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the result `String`, there is no need to create intermediate `String`s nor splitting into several parts just to tack them together afterwards. Just iterate over the matching index within the `String` and create one result `String`:

```
static String getResponse(String str, int level) {
    for(int index=str.length(); index>0; index=str.lastIndexOf('.', index-1))
        if(level-- == 0) return str.substring(0, index);
    if(level==0) return "";
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(str+" has not enough dots");
}
```

This doesn’t use any Java 8 feature but it’s also hard to imagine how Java 8 features may improve this simple operation…